# Apps randomly can't access Finder/Files MacOS Monterey 12

Tags: finder, permission, filesystem, privacy

I am using Monterey 12.5 on a new MacBook (week old), and randomly apps will not be able to interact with the file system. Chrome, photoshop, illustrator... Anything I've installed. I restart the app and it will be able to interact, but then randomly, like because it's Tuesday or something, all calls to the file system will result in nothing happening. This happens on a per-app basis, not all apps on the same day.

The first few days I used the computer I had dozens of the "{App Name} would like to access x" popups when using the apps I installed and so I figure that Chrome, Illustrator, etc... should have `user-preference-read or file-read-data sandbox access`. **But most of the apps** I have installed do not show up in the System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Files and Folders list even though I have given Chrome, Illustrator, etc. permission to folders via the darn permission popups as mentioned.

I ended up *giving all my essential apps full disk access** because it was too much of a headache (opinion - I mean I have used all these apps for years where they had "full disk access", so I will just hope their distributions don't get compromised as I did before the sandbox). [Why is there no way to manually give apps access to folders? There is a plus button on the app list in privacy settings for folders](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/control-access-to-files-and-folders-on-mac-mchld5a35146/mac), but [as confirmed in other posts this button is useless](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/373430/add-an-app-and-give-it-permissions-to-access-downloads-in-catalina?rq=1).

Any other workaround to get the apps to ask/re-ask for access themselves? These apps are used by everyone so it is strange that I am having issues with the sandboxing.

* This didn't fix the issue!: I still get the behavior of apps not being able to interact with files, but it only happens occasionally (like every couple of weeks), instead of daily.

#### Update

Here are some more details via the errors (logged via Console) that occur:

##### Trying to save - Google Chrome

```
error 14:59:11.262093-0700 com.apple.appkit.xpc.openAndSavePanelService _LSSharedFileListItemCopyResolvedURL failed for <private> with Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4
error 14:59:11.262442-0700 com.apple.appkit.xpc.openAndSavePanelService TCFURLInfo::OSStatusFromCFErrorShallow CFError = Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4
fault 14:59:13.259689-0700 contentlinkingd Couldn't read values in CFPrefsPlistSource<0x12c10b6c0> (Domain: kCFPreferencesAnyApplication, User: kCFPreferencesCurrentUser, ByHost: Yes, Container: (null), Contents Need Refresh: Yes): accessing these preferences requires user-preference-read or file-read-data sandbox access
error 14:59:08.204911-0700 Google Chrome Unable to display save panel (unrecognized error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=<private>})
error 14:59:08.858144-0700 kernel Sandbox: com.apple.WebKit(24087) deny(1) mach-lookup com.apple.diagnosticd
error 14:59:13.259100-0700 kernel Sandbox: contentlinkingd(43796) deny(1) user-preference-read kCFPreferencesAnyApplication
```

##### Trying to Open a file - Google Chrome

```
error 15:05:52.609822-0700 cfprefsd rejecting read of { kCFPreferencesAnyApplication, kCFPreferencesAnyUser, kCFPreferencesCurrentHost, /Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist, managed: 0 } from process 43796 (contentlinkingd) because accessing these preferences requires user-preference-read or file-read-data sandbox access
error 15:05:52.610981-0700 cfprefsd rejecting read of { kCFPreferencesAnyApplication, myUserName, kCFPreferencesCurrentHost, /Users/myUserName/Library/Preferences/ByHost/.GlobalPreferences.DD940F56-AC5A-5C3E-A35C-81F18B53B2AA.plist, managed: 0 } from process 43796 (contentlinkingd) because accessing these preferences requires user-preference-read or file-read-data sandbox access
```

##### Trying to Open File - Illustrator

```
error 20:56:26.972388-0700 Adobe Illustrator Unable to display open panel (unrecognized error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=<private>})
```

So somehow all the apps I've installed are like having "entitlement" issues or something? Why do they work for a bit with file access and then stop?

There must be a file or DB somewhere where Mac OS keeps track of these app permissions that could use a reset or I could manually edit (if not too esoteric).

Or do I need to try installing apps again?.. I have like 7 chrome profiles, so not looking forward to setting those up again.

Comment: I think you have jumped to the conclusion that this is about sandboxing. What you describe is definitely not normal behavior, and is not something you would typically see with sandboxing at all. From this description alone, it sounds like you have either (a) a broken storage device (SSD/hard drive), or (b) a very weird setup. Can you add a few screenshots of the error messages you see (or how it manifests itself when an app cannot access files)? - Normally with sandboxing when you open a file in the file picker inside the program, it has now been given access to that file.

Comment: When you say "nothing happens" - do really mean nothing? You click on File > Save, and nothing happens? No file dialog? No error message?

Comment: @benwiggy Exactly. No ui error messages. A menu option or command in an app that should prompt the opening of Finder (Save as, open, download as, etc.) results in simply the closing of the menu (like normal when you click an option), or nothing if its a keyboard command. No Finder appears, no error message...

Comment: @jksoegaard perhaps I can find errors in system log...  I will look at Console next time it happens and report

Comment: ^ I will turn of full disk access to a few apps to ensure that the no Finder bug occurs. I have yet to encounter the scenario with that enabled. I will keep it on for a few apps to see if it occurs anyways, as I may be barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: Just to be sure - are you perhaps confusing Finder and the file picker? - I.e. when you say you're experiencing "Finder bugs", do you mean that the file picker is not showing up? - The file picker is not Finder (technically it's an NSOpenPanel).

Comment: Yes, it would be calls to NSOpenPanel then. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @jksoegaard So after a few hours of use today, Google Chrome today stopped working with files again. I added the error messages to the question. So this morning I was able to save and open, and then later on I got the no file access behavior. I think my computer went to sleep at some point. Not sure if that is when the change occured